# ActiveMQ Network of Brokers store and forward

Tags: activemq-classic

I am new to using ActiveMQ and am trying to understand how network of brokers works. I have read the activemq documentation as well as gone through some articles on the internet such as http://www.jakubkorab.net/2011/11/understanding-activemq-broker-networks.html

I have the following set up on my local windows desktop. There are 2 tomcat servers running on 8080 and 9080 respectively with a web application that has active mq included. The web app starts a broker on start up and hence I have the following 2 brokers when both servers are up

Broker A: Running on 61616
Broker B: Running on 61617

Broker A has network connector set to have a connection to Broker B and Broker B has a network connection to Broker A both with default configurations

I am observing the following behavior

1. When I connect to web app on server A, publish a message, start a consumer on web app on server B and try to receive the message I get the message and it gets deleted from both broker A and B. I test by try to get the message using receiveSelected subsequently and I don't get any data
2. When I connect to web app on server A, publish a message, start a consumer on web app on server A and try to receive the message I get the message and it gets deleted from both broker A and B. Same test as point 1 to check

My question is at what point does the message get deleted from the stores for both the brokers - I it only after a consumer has requested the message and acknowledged it? Does that mean that at the time of publishing the message is on the local stores of both the brokers?

Answer (score 2):

Messages are removed from storage as the consumed messages are acknowledged.  In addition, with a network of brokers, brokers consume messages from each other like regular clients except that they wait until they enough messages to equal 75% of the prefetch size, of the connection, ready to be acknowledged before sending an acknowledgement (this % is configurable, as is the prefetch size).

Since the default prefetch is 1000, that means 750 messages need to cross the bridge (network connection between two brokers) and be consumed+acknowledged by another downstream client before the one broker ackowledges the messages back to the other broker, at which time the original producing broker can remove those messages from persistent store.

A message is "onwed" only by one broker at a time in the network in this manner.

At the time of publishing, the publisher receives a response immediately from the broker to which it is connected.  Note that response may be delayed until the message is persisted on disk, or it may not - depending on several factors, including type of destination (queue vs topic vs temp dest), persistence mode of the message (PERSISTENT vs NON_PERSISTENT), transacted mode of the session, and more.  To answer the question directly, if the message is being persisted to disk synchronously, the message is only guaranteed to be in the persistent store of the broker directly serving that client once the send() or commit() call completes.

There is a lot of interaction between brokers, and between clients and brokers, that is performed asynchronously, and a lot that is performed synchronously.  Production of messages meets JMS guarantees on the local broker: send() and commit() calls are synchronous between client and broker and only complete when the guarantee is met.  Acknowledgements are asynchronous; clients always need to be prepared for a redelivery of a message in the case of lost connections or broker outages (when you consider the sequence of events between client and server, this can't be completely eliminated).  Failed sends() and commits() caused by lost connections may result in either a dropped message or a stored message (again, not completely solvable) - so, again, clients need to be prepared to handle duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. While it gives some perspective it does not answer the question I have is that in my set up the brokers appear to be working as a set. So whether irrespective of which broker I publish a message to I can receive it from either broker only that once it is received I cannot receive it again. I am making use of Spring's JMS Template with following properties set

Comment: <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
<property name="sessionAcknowledgeMode" value="#{T(javax.jms.Session).AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE}" />

Comment: JMS semantics apply.  Queues are a once-and-only-once consumption of a message across all consumers, regardless of the consumer's location in the network-of-brokers (with the redelivery caveats mentioned above).  Topics broadcast messages to all consumers.

Comment: I tried this outside my local environment and am observing confusing results listing below

Comment: My networkConnector URL is of the format static:(tcp://host1:61616,tcp:/host2:61616,tcp:/host3:61616). I am using receiveSelected to retrieve specific messages using Jms Correlation Id. I have 5 messages produced all sent to broker on host1. When I explicitly connect to host2 to receive a specific message I find that subsequently I can never get the any of the other 4 messages on host1. It appears as if the moment you make a call to receiveSelected, broker 1 forwards all messages to brokers on host2. Same cascading behavior if you go to host3 after which host1 and host2 cannot pull messages.

Comment: I found that if I disable conduitSubscriptions then the above problem gets resolved. I referred to http://fusesource.com/docs/esbent/7.1/amq_networks/FMQNetworksMessageFiltering.html. Would appreciate though on the trade offs I am likely to experience

Comment: I believe the behavior the OP is describing in these comments is because `replayWhenNoConsumers=true` has not been set on the brokers.  As a result, messages go from A to B, but are not eligible to be forwarded back to A when a consumer connects there.  Enabling `replayWhenNoConsumers` would be a much better solution to this problem than disabling `conduitSubscriptions`.